# Is there any way to use Custom Scrollbar and add Parallax effect to some elements inside?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, parallax

I'm trying to use both `react-scroll-parallax` and `smooth-scrollbar-react` but idk if that's even possible. I've figure out that by using `smooth-scrollbar-react` (same with other libraries) It's actually translateY'ing whole content instead of scrolling, that's why `react-scroll-parallax` doesn't know where to apply parallax and everything is static.

I've tried to fix that by sync somehow body scroll with content translateY, but it was not working well.

Is there any way that allow me to achive this? Mabye any scroll library that uses native scroll?

Potentially solution:
I've added invisible div and initially set its content height to content from `smooth-scrollbar-react`. Then passed it as `scrollContainer` to `ParallaxProvider` so it has native scroll reference. Still, I'm not sure if that's a great idea.